# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.Predef$.any2ArrowAssoc

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark-mllib

Can you please see the below error ,when I am running the below program using below mvn config.I am running this program from eclipse neon.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.Predef$.any2ArrowAssoc(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.config(SparkSession.scala:750)
at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.appName(SparkSession.scala:741)
at com.MLTest.JavaPCAExample.main(JavaPCAExample.java:20)
```

Comment: MVN Config:-<dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
   <artifactId>spark-mllib_2.10</artifactId>
   <version>2.1.1</version>
   <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
   <artifactId>spark-sql_2.10</artifactId>
   <version>2.1.1</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
   <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
   <version>2.13.0-M1</version>
  </dependency>

Comment: source code link:-https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/spark/examples/ml/JavaPCAExample.java

Comment: Use the correct combination of Scala version and Spark version. It looks like you have a version of Spark that was made for Scala 2.10, and you're trying to run it with Scala 2.13.0-M1. That might not work.

Comment: After change " Scala 2.10.0-M1" below error :- cannot access scala.Cloneable class file for scala.Cloneable not found
cannot access scala.reflect.ClassTag class file for scala.reflect.ClassTag not found